# For android library projects, is <uses-sdk> meaningful in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

It's all pretty much in the title.  Although I see `<uses-sdk>` specified in all the example library project's `AndroidManifest.xml` I've seen, I have a feeling it's irrelevant.

In fact, I suspect that `<uses-permission>` is also irrelevant, as are all of the attributes of `<manifest>`,  other than `package`.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: And while I'm at it, contrary to what http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html says, it is not true that manifest.xml "MUST CONTAIN" an <application> element -- library project manifests don't need this if the library project doesn't contain an application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### As of ADT r20 preview 3

Library manifests can be merged with the main application manifest. This is enabled in an ant build by specifying the property

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

[I'm not sure how to enable it in other (e.g. maven) builds; please comment here if you figure it out. I'm guessing it translates into an aapt command line argument.]

A variety of rules govern conflicts and overriding behavior.

Relative to the specific questions raised here (merging of <uses-sdk> and <uses-permission>), the rules for <uses-sdk> are:

- minSdkVersion: error if destination manifest contains a value less than the lib value; leave destination value it is same or greater than lib value, store lib value in destination only if none was specified there (defaulting to 1 if not specified in either).
- targetSdkVersion: warning if destination manifest contains a value less than the lib value; leave destination value it is same or greater than lib value, store lib value in destination only if none was specified there (defaulting to merged minSdkVersion value if not specified in either).

The rule for <uses-permission> is: add library permissions to destination if they are not already present there.  It's OK if the same permission is in both.

### If you are using ADT r20 preview 2 or earlier, the following applies:

I created a little test library project and a test app that uses it, in order to get to the bottom of this myself.  I provided a <uses-sdk> and a <uses-permission> in the library project's manifest, and omitted both of them from the application's manifest.

The result was that the library project's <uses-sdk> and <uses-permission> values were NOT merged into the application at build time, as evidenced by examining the installed app on my device using the [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&hl=en) tool.

My test code is available at https://github.com/adennie/android-library-project-manifest-test.

My conclusion is that specifying <uses-sdk> and <uses-permission> in an Android Library Project's manifest has no effect on the merged manifest of the consuming application.

Comment: I've tested both your sample project and my own one. I would agree with you, <uses-sdk> in library project is a verbose declaration.

Comment: Correct, it does nothing. Android platform developer Xav Ducrochet states this in this news group post: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/9db36f18521fca7d

Comment: In fairness, the answer from "android developer" does describe some use cases where you might still want specify values for these attributes.

Comment: Using the default built provided by android-eclipse I guess that is enabled by default (in at least r21) because I keep getting `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/mypackage/name/Manifest$permission;` for a permission (`com.mypackage.name.permission.PERMISSION_NAME`) inserted both on library and on project code. Please correct me if the error is irrelevant.

Comment: @AndyDennie When i'm using this line in my application (that using a library), whole project get errors! What's wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

possible uses of the manifest in library projects:

1. have you tried lint? it can warn you if your project is using too-new classes/methods which cannot work on the min-sdk that you've set on the manifest. 
   wanna check it out? just press the V-checkbox button near the sdk manager , as shown here:
   http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/lint-toolbar.png?attredirects=0
2. the manifest could give a clue for other people of what is required for the project to be used.
3. you can also add some test activities inside which could allow you to quickly toggle the project from library project to normal project , and do some testing on it.
4. as google has suggested in the past , library projects might have some use of the manifest in the future by being merged with all of those that use the library project.

in short , the manifest is not meaningless . it can help you a lot .

Comment: I never said that the manifest was meaningless for a library project.  I said that specifying <uses-sdk> and <uses-permission> in a library project's manifest is meaningless.

Comment: well i just proved now that both of them are not meaningless .

Comment: Fair enough, the word "meaningless" was overkill.  I've referenced your answer from mine.

Comment: yes, do note that google considers making the manifests of the library projects to have some kind of merging behavior with the project/s that use the . for now , they usually have a very small purpose , if at all .

Comment: the new adt (20 preview 3) now supports merging of manifest files for the libraries . more info here: http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview

Comment: yes, I noticed that too.  Looks interesting.  I updated my answer with some details, as best as I could determine at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If your library project doesn't depend on Specific android version then you can omit this tag.

Because uses-sdk will define the sdk version etc..

Comment: But isn't the <uses-sdk> information from the containing application project's manifest what really matters?

Comment: yes it is the containing project which will define uses-sdk for its own project not for library but also there is only one menifest file for one project. Don't know much about library projects.

Answer (score -1):

As per **[the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**, It says for `<uses-sdk>`

**The attribute** `android:minSdkVersion` is surely required and if you don't pass any then it will take **1 meaning - App will support all api versions of android** and then you will have to make your app *support all of them* if you dont pass any statically.

> Caution: If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a
>   default value of "1", which indicates that your application is
>   compatible with all versions of Android. If your application is not
>   compatible with all versions (for instance, it uses APIs introduced in
>   API Level 3) and you have not declared the proper minSdkVersion, then
>   when installed on a system with an API Level less than 3, the
>   application will crash during runtime when attempting to access the
>   unavailable APIs. For this reason, be certain to declare the
>   appropriate API Level in the minSdkVersion attribute.

**The attribute** `android:maxSdkVersion` is little bit tricky to understand..doc says,

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is
>   no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your
>   application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are
>   released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully
>   backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new
>   versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development
>   best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the
>   attribute can result in your application being removed from users'
>   devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on
>   which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic
>   system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on
>   your application before setting this attribute.

And,

> Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check
>   or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or
>   re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a
>   filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for
>   download.

That warning is to indicate **Negative points that can happen if you declare that attributes** But as you look into other side **If you are developing anything that supports some specific Android Version then The ATTRIBUTE is most useful to you.**

*The step taken to remove that attribute is to encourage developer to make their app supportive to all different(newer) version.*

Only if you developing with the version 2.0.1^ then you can say *Its not needed to write that* but If you write that *Google paly will use that as filter for presenting user*

So **My Conclusion and Advice**

use the element `<uses-sdk>` with atleast one attribute `android:minSdkVersion`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't seem to address the main point of the question, which is with regard to the significance of <uses-sdk> in the context of a library project's manifest.