# Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I just splitted my App in a Pro and Free version. Therefore I made my application a library and created two new projects.
The free version kept the `namespace` `"com.mxp.time"` and the pro version got the `namespace` `"com.sourcecastle.mytime"`.
So the free version has the same `namespace` as my library.
Everything works fine except when I start a activity from preference activity in the pro version.
There I get:

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.mxp.time/.DataManagementActivity } from ProcessRecord{45461048 30784:com.sourcecastle.mytime/u0a10012} (pid=30784, uid=10012) not exported from uid 10013
```

My Preferences.xml looks like:

```
  <!-- datamanagement -->
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="datamanagement_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
    <Preference
        android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_message"
        android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_title" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.mxp.time" />
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And my manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/datamanagement_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I already set

> “android:exported="true"

in my manifest but I still get an exception.

Additionally I have a general question: Where should I define my activities now? In the library or in the real application?
I tried to remove all permissions and activities from my library project and my app keeps working.
But since I got this problem I ask myself if this isn’t a security issue because registering my activities in my application only lets me override settings like “exported”…

Can anyone help me understand that?

UPDATE:

This seems to work:

```
  <!-- datamanagement -->
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="datamanagement_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >

    <!-- <Preference -->
    <!-- android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_message" -->
    <!-- android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_title" > -->
    <!-- <intent -->
    <!-- android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" -->
    <!-- android:targetClass="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity" -->
    <!-- android:targetPackage="com.mxp.time" /> -->
    <!-- </Preference> -->

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_message"
        android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_pref_title" >
        <intent android:action="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/datamanagement_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mxp.time.DataManagementActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And my other question is ansered here:
[Android Library Manifest vs. App Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179198/android-library-manifest-vs-app-manifest)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem for one of my activity althought I'm using libraries since years...

Answer (score 1):

Declare your Activity that way:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.sourcecastle.commons.activity.DataManagementActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/datamanagement_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sourcecastle.commons.activity.DataManagementActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In preferences.xml do it the following way:

```
 <PreferenceCategory
    android:key="datamanagement_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_message"
        android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
        <intent android:action="com.sourcecastle.commons.activity.DataManagementActivity" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Cheers,
Stefan