# How to disable RTL support in external libraries?

Tags: android

I imported a github library using gradle , it works fine except it supports RTL and my project doesn't, I tried using :

```
tools:replace="supportsRtl"
```

in my manifest but didnt work , any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

In your `manifest` file and inside the application tag add these two lines.

```
<manifest>
    <application
        .
        .
        .
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl" //(replace libraries' Rtl support with ours)
        >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

when some **libraries** have support `Rtl` , you have to make a change in their `manifest` file , so if you want to use them you must replace their `manifest` line of code with yours.

Comment: how do I access the manifest of that library cuz I add it from gradle

Comment: Check this link for more informations https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179198/android-library-manifest-vs-app-manifest&ved=2ahUKEwiBy-z4r_rhAhVLTBoKHSTvDQMQrAIoAjABegQIBxAR&usg=AOvVaw34rHSw2eQLF0tBcLkWc_0N