# Linking an Android project to another

Tags: android, android-library

I converted one project to a library project and linked it to the other, but I'm getting these errors (SearchFacebook is the library project):

```
[2012-11-02 16:29:10 - FacebookFollower] G:\AndroidProjects\FacebookUpdaterFollower\SearchFacebook\res\layout\test_results_auto_complete.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'categories' in package 'shira.android.facebook.updaterfollower.search'
[2012-11-02 16:29:10 - FacebookFollower] G:\AndroidProjects\FacebookUpdaterFollower\SearchFacebook\res\layout\test_results_auto_complete.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'max_results' in package 'shira.android.facebook.updaterfollower.search'
```

I checked the R file and the resource identifiers are there, and I'm not getting these errors when the linked project is compiled as a stand-alone project (not a library).

By the way, can I link an Android project without converting it to a library?

**UPDATE:** As was suggested, I changed the namespace of the custom attributes where they are used. My layout file in the project that uses the library now looks like this (the relevant parts):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="5dp"
xmlns:search="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<shira.android.facebook.updaterfollower.search.FacebookResultsAutoComplete 
    android:id="@+id/followed_type_auto_complete" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:hint="@string/followed_type" 
    search:max_results="15"/>
```

However, I'm still getting the same errors as before, and I updated the Android Tools to the latest version, so what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you accessing max_results from your main project? And if so is max_results in your library?

Comment: max_results is in my library, but I'm not accessing it from the main project, just from the library project.

Comment: Did you have these errors before you converted it to the library?

Comment: No, that's why I don't understand why I'm getting them now.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the projects?

Comment: Yes, cleaned them and built again, same errors...

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398416/using-activities-from-library-projects/10627478#10627478) helps.

Comment: Try downloading the latest eclipse IDE.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're stuck with a known bug caused by custom attributes in library projects.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656

Luckily, there has been a fix introduced with the r17 android tools. [Comment 71](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656#c71) on the issue should point you to a working solution.

Comment: I updated my version, changed the namespace, and am still getting the same errors...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe The class which use the method, needs to be import that packages

Answer (score 1):

Need more information about your implementation. you can provide code snippet(`not complete`) here to support your question.

1. provide two of your packages(main,lib) you are using.(`need not to be original`).(**MUST BE UNIQUE**)
2. make sure you have not repeated the same resource ids in library project as well as in main project.(in case choose different)
3. check your import package query for `R` file. (**It's very important**) where the correct R file imported.

When I was working with library projects the `R` file got imported very often as **android.R** and I resolved after a long time by importing with it's relevant R file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can I change a resource ID? And I'm using explicit reference to any resource which is not in the same application package, so I don't need to import the R file. The layout file which causes the errors is attached above.

Comment: here Importing R file means "In case your IDE imported wrong(Default) R file and you might be expecting something else." That's what I wanted to be sure. Anyways sorry I missed about your custom attribute. In my project I have not used custom attribute :(. So what I suspect is your problem might be due to that custom attributes. Try copying attribute xml to your main project(not tested from my end).

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the library project gen and remove it's entire content.
Do the same for the main project. 
Choose project -> clean  from the eclipse option menu.
When all is done choose build and see if the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the project as jar and then use it in the other project as a jar file. Hope this helps..