# Do libraries uses-permission and other tags move to applications?

Tags: android

I am creating a library

Do uses-permissions tags move on the application that is using that library?

The application tag doesn't matter, correct?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html. check library projects

Comment: I think that the accepted answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503705/for-android-library-projects-is-uses-sdk-meaningful-in-manifest][1] is valid for you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503705/for-android-library-projects-is-uses-sdk-meaningful-in-manifest