# Android - after making a project library dependent on another which manifest is used in build

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries, android-manifest

Having two projects i decided to link one as a dependency to another project.  The dependent project will have a res folder and host some resources like drawables and string.xml files etc.  This way i can build other projects that use the same resources and have them dependent on this project.  I might put class files in this library project as well.

below is a diagram of an example library dependency in eclipse i am creating:

PROJECT A ----> PROJECT I

PROJECT B ----> PROJECT I

PROJECT C ----> PROJECT I

So as you can see the project I would contain any resources i dont want to duplicate.  I want to put a few android activities in this PROJECT I  thus it will contain a manifest.  At compile time which manifest gets used to put into the apk archive file ?

Also if anyone knows of any tutorials on making an android project a dependent library on another one i'd like to see how the manifest was arranged.

Comment: I thinks here you would find your answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503705/for-android-library-projects-is-uses-sdk-meaningful-in-manifest/10400355#10400355

Comment: this looks like exactly what im looking for,thanks.